# Get the absolute path of any file in symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to follow the small tutorial here http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/finder.html but I'm just absolutely lost on how to actually find a file.  I guess I have two problems to solve.

1)  What's a good method in Symfony to determine the `/path/to/src` from say the controller?

2)  How do I use Finder to get the absolute path to my desired file?

In a partial answer to 1 I'm aware of `$this->get('kernel')->getRootDir()` but that points to `/path/to/app` and I guess I could just add `../src` to the end but I would like something a little cleaner.

I would prefer to crawl through subdirectories rather than specify just a single folder to look in.

Here's what I've tried

```
/* In this case the actual file exists in src/MyBundle/config/myFile.xml */
$finder = new Finder();

$finder->files()->name('myFile.xml')->in('/path/to/src');
```

Or I've also done.

```
$finder->files()->name('myFile.xml')->in('/path/to/src/MyBundle/config');
```

Finder throws an error if the directory doesn't exist.  So I know there's not an error with my path string.  But when I try to `foreach($finder as $file)` through the results or `$finder->getIterator()` I just end up with `NULL` every time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The intent of the Finder component is to provide an easy way to iterate through files and directories on a disk. It is not intended to be used with only one file and if the path to that file is not known.

In order to get directory the PHP file is located at you can use `__DIR__`. For example, if your code is in the `Controller` directory of your bundle

```
echo __DIR__.'/../Resources/config/myFile.xml';
```

You can use Finder if you want to iterate through all XML files in the config directory.

```
$finder->files()->name('*.xml')->in(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config');
```

Comment: Yeah I kinda figured this was where the question was heading.  If only they hosted their wsdl like the rest of the world instead of just emailing it to me and saying, "here ya go.  We know you like SOAP so lets make it even more fun!"